# How to replace each 3rd or 4th character in a string with a newline? C#

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

For instance I've got this string: "Is it allowed to enter this room without asking?"

I'd like to place each 3rd or 4th ' ' a newline to get it to be like: "Is it allowed to(newline)enter this room without(newline)without asking?"

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Did you already write any code?

Comment: No a Unity project where I wanted to display the question on a screen and making it fit. I used to do this manually adding '@' at the spot to 'newline' but that doesn't work out.

Comment: You know there are other ways to wrap text?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a  very verbose solution, based on the assumption that each word is separated by others only with a space.

```
var splitted = "Is it allowed to enter this room without asking?".Split(' ');
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
int i = 1;
foreach (var word in splitted)
{
     str.Append(word);
     if (i % 3 == 0)
     {
         str.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
     }
     else
     {
          str.Append(" ");
     }
     i++;
 }

 var result = str.ToString();
```

Comment: Implicit variable declaration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx  You can substitute it with `string`, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string text = "Is it allowed to enter this room without asking?";
        string newText = null;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            string temp = c.ToString();
            if (c == ' ')
            {
                count ++;
                bool placeNewLine = false;
                Random random = new Random();
                if (random.Next(0, 2) == 1) placeNewLine = true;
                if (count == 4 || (placeNewLine && count ==3))
                {
                    temp = Environment.NewLine;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            newText += temp;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(newText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```